# GORM One to Many relationship across multiple datasources

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I see there is a strategy for a one to one mapping for domain objects across different databases. But I am trying to associate two Domain objects that are in different datasources and have a one to many relationship.

```
class DomainA {
    // default data source
}

class DomainB {
    static hasmany = [domainA: DomainA]

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'ds2'
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work? Or a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this and it works pretty well. Solution is to create a join table in the schema you own. 
E.g.

```
class DomainA {
    // default data source
}

class DomainB {
    List<DomainA> domainAList
    static transients = ['domainAList']
    static hasmany = [domainAIds: Integer]

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'ds2'
        domainAIds joinTable: [name: 'DOMAINB_DOMAINA', key: 'DOMAINB_ID', column: 'DOMAINA_ID']
    }

    List<DomainA> getDomainAList(){
        domainAList = domainAIds.collect { DomainA.get(it) }
        domainAList 
    }
}
```